# Filtering array from json file in React

Tags: reactjs, arrays, json, filter

I have a json file (questions) with an array of objects in it.

I have one line of code filtering those objects that works perfectly:
`const allAnswers = questions.filter(q => q.Ending === question).map(q => q.Parsing)`

I tried to add a filter before that line to filter the list of questions based on user input
`const qlist = questions.filter(q => q.Group <= level)`
This filter does not work at all, it returns an empty array

It is definitely finding the object property "Group", because I can console log it using questions[1].Group.
I have checked that Group and level are both numbers.

The most annoying bit is it did work exactly once but I can't work out what I did.

```json
[
    {
        "Ending": "a",
        "Parsing": "singular nominative",
        "POS": "Noun",
        "Group": 1
    },
    {
        "Ending": "a",
        "Parsing": "singular vocative",
        "POS": "Noun",
        "Group": 1
    },
    {
        "Ending": "am",
        "Parsing": "singular accusative",
        "POS": "Noun",
        "Group": 1
    },
    {
        "Ending": "ae",
        "Parsing": "singular genitive",
        "POS": "Noun",
        "Group": 1
    },
    {
        "Ending": "ae",
        "Parsing": "singular dative",
        "POS": "Noun",
        "Group": 1
    },
    {
        "Ending": "a",
        "Parsing": "singular ablative",
        "POS": "Noun",
        "Group": 1
    },
    {
        "Ending": "ae",
        "Parsing": "plural nominative",
        "POS": "Noun",
        "Group": 1
    },
    {
        "Ending": "ae",
        "Parsing": "plural vocative",
        "POS": "Noun",
        "Group": 1
    },
    {
        "Ending": "as",
        "Parsing": "plural accusative",
        "POS": "Noun",
        "Group": 1
    },
    {
        "Ending": "arum",
        "Parsing": "plural genitive",
        "POS": "Noun",
        "Group": 1
    },
    {
        "Ending": "is",
        "Parsing": "plural dative",
        "POS": "Noun",
        "Group": 1
    },
    {
        "Ending": "is",
        "Parsing": "plural ablative",
        "POS": "Noun",
        "Group": 1
    },
    {
        "Ending": "us",
        "Parsing": "singular nominative",
        "POS": "Noun",
        "Group": 2
    },
    {
        "Ending": "er",
        "Parsing": "singular nominative",
        "POS": "Noun",
        "Group": 2
    },
    {
        "Ending": "e",
        "Parsing": "singular vocative",
        "POS": "Noun",
        "Group": 2
    },
    {
        "Ending": "er",
        "Parsing": "singular vocative",
        "POS": "Noun",
        "Group": 2
    },
    {
        "Ending": "um",
        "Parsing": "singular accusative",
        "POS": "Noun",
        "Group": 2
    },
    {
        "Ending": "i",
        "Parsing": "singular genitive",
        "POS": "Noun",
        "Group": 2
    },
    {
        "Ending": "o",
        "Parsing": "singular dative",
        "POS": "Noun",
        "Group": 2
    },
    {
        "Ending": "o",
        "Parsing": "singular ablative",
        "POS": "Noun",
        "Group": 2
    },
    {
        "Ending": "i",
        "Parsing": "plural nominative",
        "POS": "Noun",
        "Group": 2
    },
    {
        "Ending": "i",
        "Parsing": "plural vocative",
        "POS": "Noun",
        "Group": 2
    },
    {
        "Ending": "os",
        "Parsing": "plural accusative",
        "POS": "Noun",
        "Group": 2
    },
    {
        "Ending": "orum",
        "Parsing": "plural genitive",
        "POS": "Noun",
        "Group": 2
    },
    {
        "Ending": "is",
        "Parsing": "plural dative",
        "POS": "Noun",
        "Group": 2
    },
    {
        "Ending": "is",
        "Parsing": "plural ablative",
        "POS": "Noun",
        "Group": 2
    },
    {
        "Ending": "um",
        "Parsing": "singular nominative",
        "POS": "Noun",
        "Group": 2
    },
    {
        "Ending": "um",
        "Parsing": "singular vocative",
        "POS": "Noun",
        "Group": 2
    },
    {
        "Ending": "a",
        "Parsing": "plural nominative",
        "POS": "Noun",
        "Group": 2
    },
    {
        "Ending": "a",
        "Parsing": "plural vocative",
        "POS": "Noun",
        "Group": 2
    },
    {
        "Ending": "a",
        "Parsing": "plural accusative",
        "POS": "Noun",
        "Group": 2
    },
    {
        "Ending": "em",
        "Parsing": "singular accusative",
        "POS": "Noun",
        "Group": 3
    },
    {
        "Ending": "is",
        "Parsing": "singular genitive",
        "POS": "Noun",
        "Group": 3
    },
    {
        "Ending": "i",
        "Parsing": "singular dative",
        "POS": "Noun",
        "Group": 3
    },
    {
        "Ending": "e",
        "Parsing": "singular ablative",
        "POS": "Noun",
        "Group": 3
    },
    {
        "Ending": "i",
        "Parsing": "singular ablative",
        "POS": "Noun",
        "Group": 3
    },
    {
        "Ending": "es",
        "Parsing": "plural nominative",
        "POS": "Noun",
        "Group": 3
    },
    {
        "Ending": "es",
        "Parsing": "plural vocative",
        "POS": "Noun",
        "Group": 3
    },
    {
        "Ending": "es",
        "Parsing": "plural accusative",
        "POS": "Noun",
        "Group": 3
    },
    {
        "Ending": "um",
        "Parsing": "plural genitive",
        "POS": "Noun",
        "Group": 3
    },
    {
        "Ending": "ium",
        "Parsing": "plural genitive",
        "POS": "Noun",
        "Group": 3
    },
    {
        "Ending": "ibus",
        "Parsing": "plural dative",
        "POS": "Noun",
        "Group": 3
    },
    {
        "Ending": "ibus",
        "Parsing": "plural ablative",
        "POS": "Noun",
        "Group": 3
    },
    {
        "Ending": "ia",
        "Parsing": "plural nominative",
        "POS": "Noun",
        "Group": 3
    },
    {
        "Ending": "ia",
        "Parsing": "plural vocative",
        "POS": "Noun",
        "Group": 3
    },
    {
        "Ending": "ia",
        "Parsing": "plural accusative",
        "POS": "Noun",
        "Group": 3
    },
    {
        "Ending": "a",
        "Parsing": "plural nominative",
        "POS": "Noun",
        "Group": 3
    },
    {
        "Ending": "a",
        "Parsing": "plural vocative",
        "POS": "Noun",
        "Group": 3
    },
    {
        "Ending": "a",
        "Parsing": "plural accusative",
        "POS": "Noun",
        "Group": 3
    },
    {
        "Ending": "us",
        "Parsing": "singular nominative",
        "POS": "Noun",
        "Group": 4
    },
    {
        "Ending": "us",
        "Parsing": "singular vocative",
        "POS": "Noun",
        "Group": 4
    },
    {
        "Ending": "um",
        "Parsing": "singular accusative",
        "POS": "Noun",
        "Group": 4
    },
    {
        "Ending": "us",
        "Parsing": "singular genitive",
        "POS": "Noun",
        "Group": 4
    },
    {
        "Ending": "ui",
        "Parsing": "singular dative",
        "POS": "Noun",
        "Group": 4
    },
    {
        "Ending": "ui",
        "Parsing": "singular ablative",
        "POS": "Noun",
        "Group": 4
    },
    {
        "Ending": "u",
        "Parsing": "singular ablative",
        "POS": "Noun",
        "Group": 4
    },
    {
        "Ending": "ua",
        "Parsing": "plural nominative",
        "POS": "Noun",
        "Group": 4
    },
    {
        "Ending": "ua",
        "Parsing": "plural vocative",
        "POS": "Noun",
        "Group": 4
    },
    {
        "Ending": "ua",
        "Parsing": "plural accusative",
        "POS": "Noun",
        "Group": 4
    },
    {
        "Ending": "us",
        "Parsing": "plural nominative",
        "POS": "Noun",
        "Group": 4
    },
    {
        "Ending": "us",
        "Parsing": "plural vocative",
        "POS": "Noun",
        "Group": 4
    },
    {
        "Ending": "us",
        "Parsing": "plural accusative",
        "POS": "Noun",
        "Group": 4
    },
    {
        "Ending": "uum",
        "Parsing": "plural genitive",
        "POS": "Noun",
        "Group": 4
    },
    {
        "Ending": "ibus",
        "Parsing": "plural dative",
        "POS": "Noun",
        "Group": 4
    },
    {
        "Ending": "ibus",
        "Parsing": "plural ablative",
        "POS": "Noun",
        "Group": 4
    },
    {
        "Ending": "es",
        "Parsing": "singular nominative",
        "POS": "Noun",
        "Group": 5
    },
    {
        "Ending": "es",
        "Parsing": "singular vocative",
        "POS": "Noun",
        "Group": 5
    },
    {
        "Ending": "em",
        "Parsing": "singular accusative",
        "POS": "Noun",
        "Group": 5
    },
    {
        "Ending": "ei",
        "Parsing": "singular genitive",
        "POS": "Noun",
        "Group": 5
    },
    {
        "Ending": "ei",
        "Parsing": "singular dative",
        "POS": "Noun",
        "Group": 5
    },
    {
        "Ending": "e",
        "Parsing": "singular ablative",
        "POS": "Noun",
        "Group": 5
    },
    {
        "Ending": "es",
        "Parsing": "plural nominative",
        "POS": "Noun",
        "Group": 5
    },
    {
        "Ending": "es",
        "Parsing": "plural vocative",
        "POS": "Noun",
        "Group": 5
    },
    {
        "Ending": "es",
        "Parsing": "plural accusative",
        "POS": "Noun",
        "Group": 5
    },
    {
        "Ending": "erum",
        "Parsing": "plural genitive",
        "POS": "Noun",
        "Group": 5
    },
    {
        "Ending": "ebus",
        "Parsing": "plural dative",
        "POS": "Noun",
        "Group": 5
    },
    {
        "Ending": "ebus",
        "Parsing": "plural ablative",
        "POS": "Noun",
        "Group": 5
    }
]
```

Comment: please share the json sample lines and code for level and html

Comment: JSON looks like this
`
    {
        "Ending": "a",
        "Parsing": "singular nominative",
        "POS": "Noun",
        "Group": 1
    },
    {
        "Ending": "a",
        "Parsing": "singular vocative",
        "POS": "Noun",
        "Group": 1
    },`
Level is coming from useParams, passed from another component
`const l = useParams()
 const level = Number(l)`

Comment: @HapaxHypatia in the snippet you provided all (two) objects have the same `Group` value, so any filtering on that property would either return all of them or none of them. Other than that, the `filter` you shared seems to work just fine. Can you include a [mcve]?

Comment: I've edited the post, as it was too long for a comment. Thanks for the help

Comment: Looks like `l` would be `undefined`. Can you print it out to the console and check its value?

Comment: You're right, it is. I didn't have it like that originally, I had the conversion to number somewhere else, and I thought the level was coming through ok then. Let me check.

Comment: Ah. I have a console log of the level in the component that's passing it and got them confused. So I guess it was never passing properly in the first place.

Comment: The level is added to the url correctly: http://localhost:3000/quizpage/4
But useParams logs as  [object Object]

Comment: Working now, thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem isn't with the filtering, but with the way you get the `l` value from the parameters.

`useParams` returns an object, and you should extract the value of `l` from it. E.g.:

```js
// Note that this way `l` isn't the object, but an attribute of the object
const {l} = useParams();
```